How do I find the Curses Module
How do I find the "curses" module for python? I cannot find it anywhere and whatever I tried I could not obtain any useful results or information, I also checked in visual studio code extensions and found nothing.
I tried searching on multiple websites on the internet, including this one, but could not find any good answers.

There's nothing to install. It's builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html

...so if it's not built-in for you, then your version of Python was presumably compiled without it. (That's unusual, and raises a question of whether you installed Python in some atypical way rather than via distro-provided package).

VS Code extensions are not made for installing Python modules. Python modules can be installed with pip, the official Python package management tool, or your system's packet manager, or a third-party package management tool (like conda or poetry).

However the curses module isn't an installable module and is part of the standard library (modules built-in python). You probably have a version of Python compiled without it or your system may not support curses. Could you provide information about your Python setup? (version, where you downloaded it from)
